# how to convert date format in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a data frame that contains the information below :

```
N_Ord   PSN      debut_interval
1      A4BA0D07  01/01/2022
2      04BB0607  01/01/2022
```

I need to

- convert the `debut_interval` of each row of my dataframe to that format **yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00**
- add a new column `fin_interval` that contains the same date like that **yyyy-mm-ddT23:59:59**

Comment: Have you seen [the docs describing `strptime` and `strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)? If so, what part do you need help understanding?

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and explain how it's doing doing what you want.

Comment: @joanis okey i need to request an API with an intarval of time the request seems like that ```url = "https://aaa.com/mw/psn/"+row['PSN']+"/record/16?key=nLsBvp0YedcXUcaU73fs&from_date="+start_date+"&"+end_date``` i have a dataframe like show in the question i need to convert all dates format of my dataframe to the format ```yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss``` where start_date= **yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00** and end_date=**yyyy-mm-ddT23:59:59**

Comment: Yes, that's more about what you want to do, but have you even tried anything, or are you just hoping someone on SO will write the code for you? I'm afraid this site is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: @joanis i tried the **ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")** but it gives me an error **'str' object has no attribute 'ToString'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
df2 = (df
  .assign(debut_interval=pd.to_datetime(df['debut_interval'], dayfirst=True),
          fin_interval=lambda d: d['debut_interval'].add(pd.to_timedelta('23:59:59')).dt.strftime(fmt))
  .assign(debut_interval=lambda d: d['debut_interval'].dt.strftime(fmt)
          )
       )
```

Output:

```
   N_Ord       PSN       debut_interval         fin_interval
0      1  A4BA0D07  2022-01-01T00:00:00  2022-01-01T23:59:59
1      2  04BB0607  2022-01-01T00:00:00  2022-01-01T23:59:59
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_date(fmt):
    fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT" + fmt
    return lambda x: x.dt.strftime(fmt)

df['debut_interval'] = pd.to_datetime(df['debut_interval'])
df.debut_interval.transform({'debut_interval':get_date('00:00:00'),
                            'fin_interval':get_date('23:59:59')})
 
        debut_interval         fin_interval
0  2022-01-01T00:00:00  2022-01-01T23:59:59
1  2022-01-01T00:00:00  2022-01-01T23:59:59
```